# how to make android time picker to not allow past time being picked

Tags: android

HI am new to android and i want to not allow past time being picked by using time picker..
i tried with the following code

```
private TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener StartTimeChangedListener=new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener()
    {
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view,int selectedHour,int selectedMinute)
        {
            update(view,selectedHour,selectedMinute);
        }
    };
```

and i dont know how to write the code for update(view,selectedHour,selectedMinute); can anybody help me please...

Comment: This is a logic issue, how would **YOU** verify if the time has passed? What signifies this?

Comment: JoxTraex yeah that's right. its totally depends on how you put logic for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried following the [tutorial on the developers page](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html) for the timepicker?

**Edit:**

Ok, so following the tutorial we have the update method for the textview that will show your time:

```
private void updateDisplay() {
    mTimeDisplay.setText(
        new StringBuilder()
                .append(pad(mHour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(mMinute)));
}

private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}
```

The dialog that will be created for the user to pick the time:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is where I would add the restriction that you want, the callback method when the user sets the time. You need to get the current hour and minute, and if the user selects a past time, you do not display his changes and send him a Toast or something.

Using the Calendar you can easily get it:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();           

// the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialog
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
           if (mHour >= Integer.getInteger(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) && mMinute >= Integer.getInteger(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))) { 
            mHour = hourOfDay;
            mMinute = minute;                
            updateDisplay();
            } else 
            //Display a toast or something to inform the user that he can't pick a past time.   
        }
```

Now if you want the user to not be able to pick a previous time in the Dialog you created, you have to create your own hour picking screen, because the TimePickerDialog has no restrictions about what values you can pick.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i tried in that tutorial but that just modifies the time what we picked

Comment: but my issue is not allow past time being picked

Comment: Just don't forget that what I've wrote is my approach to the problem. It's not by any means the only, or the best way to do this.

Comment: private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
  public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,int selectedMinute) {

   if(selectedHour<hour)
   {
//    view.setOnTimeSetListener(NullTimeChangedListener);

          // set minute
          view.setCurrentMinute(minute);

          //set hour
          view.setCurrentHour(hour);

          tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":").append(pad(minute)));

Comment: its shows the error at the Integer.getInteger() method can u tell me the correct solution

Comment: but this doesn't prevent the user from selecting the unwanted time, it's only notify after the user selection!

Answer (score 1):

```
if((hourOfDay <= (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)))&&
        (minute <= (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)))){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong hour",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code a little and it works for me:
I have taken both date and time picker in one alert dialog box and write some code when someone wants to set the time for alarm through its positive button.

```
       final DatePicker pickdate = (DatePicker) view
                .findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
       final TimePicker pickTime = (TimePicker) view
                .findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Set Alarm Time",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        int day = pickdate.getDayOfMonth();
                        int month = pickdate.getMonth();
                        int year = pickdate.getYear();

                        int hour = pickTime.getCurrentHour();
                        int min = pickTime.getCurrentMinute();
                        c = Calendar.getInstance();

      if (min >= c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
      && hour >= c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
      && day >= c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
      && (month + 1) >= c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
      && year >= c.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {

  String setdate = year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-"
  + day + " " + hour + ":" + min;

  //Use the string where you wants
 }

    else {
         //show some error toast
     Toast.makeText(context,
     Html.fromHtml("<font color=RED><em><strong>Past Time  Can't Be Added</strong></em>/font>")
    ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```